# What's the difference between these two

Tags: difference, will-would

> 1.How long will it last?
>
> 2.How long would it last?

One is present and the other is past?

In what context I can use them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Would" is used in conditional clauses.  The second sentence implies that the speaker is either going to follow with "If...." or this "If" statement can be understood from the context:

> Let's suppose the moon is made of cheese; how long would it last?

The first statement simply asks for a prediction of the future, with no particular condition being given.

> Oil is running out; how long will it last?